# In Spider-Man No Way Home, how did *this* character not face the same consequences as other characters in the similar situation?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-no-way-home

Just got back from watching No Way Home for the second time, but unfortunately none of my friends care about these things as much as I do -for them this is just 'another movie'.
But I have a lot of burning questions and a lot of things that I want to discuss with fellow fans who care as much as I do, hence I came here.

Also, even though this is not so crucial to the plot, I will still be making sure that nothing is spoiled, hence the spoiler warning and spoiler tags.

So basically, while I watch watching the movie the second time, I realised that

> Flash Thompson did not face the same consequences as Ned and MJ, even though he is more vocal about his (non-existent) 'friendship' with Peter/Spider-Man, and has also written a book about their adventures together.

Later on, during the bridge scene,

> we also see the same book in the hands of the lady who is from the admissions team at MIT.

Why don't people

> hate Flash, and why isn't his admission to MIT affected 'in the light of recent controversies"

Answer (score 10):

It’s apparent that everyone knows Flash’s best-friends-with-Spider-Man routine is at best an exaggeration, and at worst an outright fabrication. This is why Peter’s offer to “tell everyone they’re best friends” is good leverage for Flash to do him a favor.

Also, since Flash’s “memoir” is a work of fiction, it is published as such for legal reasons. To promote No Way Home, a [real-life issue](https://www.reddit.com/r/Spiderman/comments/rddw63/they_have_a_daily_bugle_stand_in_nyc_handing_out/) of the Daily Bugle newspaper was produced and distributed on the streets of New York. It includes a review of the memoir which calls out Flash for including an “all persons fictitious” disclaimer, implying that it’s obvious he isn’t being entirely truthful.

It’s possible the Vice Chancellor of MIT only had that copy of Flash’s book because he gave it to her at the mixer they had both just attended. She is certainly an intelligent woman, so either way I find it unlikely that she of all people would fall for his charade, let alone the entire MIT admissions team.

All things considered, I would go so far as to say the book may have even helped his chances of getting into MIT, since being a published author shows many characteristics they might look for in a candidate.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But this just raises a new question - is the MIT team willing to admit liars / exaggerators?